# Why do electrons in a conductor not connected to a power source not fly away due to repulsion?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge

Let's assume that a conducting element is kept on a table (to indicate that no power source is connected across its ends). So, all the electrons move in random directions and repel each other. The question I have is *"Why do they not fly away?"*

I think that they don't have enough energy to escape the strong pull of the nucleus which is positively charged. They get that energy when they are connected to a power source i.e. when there is some electromotive force to push them by increasing their energy levels. The latter is what happens in a wire when its ends are connected to the terminals of a cell/battery.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Rajdeep, please note that *check my work* type questions are considered *off-topic* by the community and are quite often closed by community vote. Your question seems to be of this type to me (*"Let me know if I have made the slightest of a mistake"*).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean it to be like that. What I meant by it was more like *"Please let me know if I'm totally right or partially right."*

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Is the edit fine?

Comment: Rajdeep, I have edited your question. You may revert it if you're not happy with the edit.

Comment: It's great @AlfredCentauri thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not really correct. The electrons bound in atoms don't carry the current. It is true that these electrons don't escape because of this, but I don't think its what the question is asking for given the electrostatics tag. Electrons that carry current in a conductor are free electrons, so I think you should talk about field emission.

Comment: So, the part that says  that they don't "fly away" because of the attraction of the nucleus is right and the next one about the power source is not?

Comment: jamie, don't electrons carry (electric) charge rather than current? Also, isn't it *mobile* electrons rather than *free* electrons?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu I would make it extra clear I was talking about free electrons. I don't understand why you wrote the second part, it is not related to the question.

Comment: @jamie I get it. The first part is the one concerned  with the answer and the second part is unnecessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Electrons don't simply leave their neighbouring atoms because they repel. They also feel attraction to these atoms and so are not completely free to escape. 
When we apply current to a conductor, some electrons called free electrons (it is believed they are not so glued to any nucleus) start moving in the direction of the electric field throughout the core of the material and this is what causes current to flow.
Without this potential, the electrons simply vibrate and are held together by the attraction of the protons in the nucleus.